# Any alternatives to dyn when your trait is not object-safe?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

I want to do a program that uses the command line arguments to the select the used structs. Something like this:

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn sound(&self) -> &str;
}

struct Dog {}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn sound(&self) -> &str {
        "Woof!"
    }
}

struct Cat {}

impl Animal for Cat {
    fn sound(&self) -> &str {
        "Miau!"
    }
}

trait Place {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

struct Museum {}

impl Place for Museum {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        "museum"
    }
}

struct Hotel{}

impl Place for Hotel {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        "hotel"
    }
}

fn get_animal(animal: &str) -> Box<dyn Animal> {
    match animal {
        "dog" => Box::new(Dog{}),
        "cat" => Box::new(Cat{}),
        _ => todo!()
    }
}

fn get_place(place: &str) -> Box<dyn Place> {
    match place {
        "museum" => Box::new(Museum{}),
        "hotel" => Box::new(Hotel{}),
        _ => todo!()
    }
}

fn sentence(animal: Box<dyn Animal>, place: Box<dyn Place>) {
    println!("{} We are at {}.", animal.sound(), place.name());
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let animal = get_animal(&args[1]);
    let place = get_place(&args[2]);
    
    sentence(animal, place);
}
```

However, I am using traits that are not object-safe, so I cannot use `dyn`. Now I am just using a `match` for every combination:

```rust
match (animal, place) {
    ("dog", "museum") => sentence(Dog{}, Museum{}),
    ("dog", "hotel") => sentence(Dog{}, Hotel{}),
    ("cat", "museum") => sentence(Cat{}, Museum{}),
    ("cat", "hotel") => sentence(Cat{}, Hotel{}),
}
```

However, I am going to add many more structs to my program so this is not scalable. Is there any scalable way to solve this problem? Is it possible to create a macro that generates the `match` so I do not have to write it manually or is there any better solution?

The traits I am using are:

- PrimeField: https://docs.rs/ark-ff/latest/ark_ff/fields/trait.PrimeField.html
- ConstraintSynthesizer: https://docs.rs/ark-relations/latest/ark_relations/r1cs/trait.ConstraintSynthesizer.html
- PolynomialCommitment: https://docs.rs/ark-poly-commit/latest/ark_poly_commit/trait.PolynomialCommitment.html

Probably modifying the traits to make them object-safe is not a good idea for two reasons:

1. This libraries execute complex mathematical algorithms that are not easy to understand.
2. The program is used to benchmark the libraries. Maybe modifying the traits could alter the performance of the libraries.

Comment: We'd have to see your actual traits, not some example traits that don't apply to your situation. The solution is likely to make the traits object-safe in some way, but we can't help figure it out if we don't know why they aren't object-safe.

Comment: @cdhowie The traits are from a library so I don't want to modify them. However, I am going add the traits so you have more information about the problem.

Comment: I'd have to see how you want to use the trait objects as well. One solution is to write an object-safe version of the trait and implement that on a generic newtype that wraps a concrete value, but it's hard to say if this will work without knowing how you intend to use the values.

Comment: @cdhowie This is the code: https://github.com/jesusvico/tfm-marlin/blob/master/src/main.rs There is a `bench()` function that uses the specified structs to generate a benchmark of them.

Comment: Rust is not C++, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc647e3160f1cfc2c67286fab177d9d4 thus I don't know if this can be applied to your case haha I didn't look to your link yet

Comment: @Stargateur I really like your solution but I cannot implement StrFrom for `PrimeField` trait `error[E0782]: trait objects must include the \`dyn\` keyword`. This is because `PrimeField` is not an object-safe trait.

Comment: @Prankster2k Your question and the link you shared have nothing to do with one another. The `bench` function doesn't actually take any values of the generic types as its arguments, therefore `dyn` values wouldn't even make any sense, no? And especially since the types of `C` and `A` depend on the type of `F`, this makes `dyn` unsuitable.

Comment: @cdhowie The `bench` function doesn't take any values of the generic types because the traits are not object-safe so I cannot use them as args.

Comment: @Prankster2k Even still, the types of `C` and `A` depend on the type of `F` so `dyn` will not help you here. You may be able to simplify the giant `match` using macros, though.

Comment: @cdhowie You are right. Do you have any idea about how to do the macro?

Comment: Are there static methods (methods without receiver) in the trait (that you need to call)?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two reasons why a trait will not be object-safe:

- because it includes a generic function,
- and/or because it includes a function that doesn't have a receiver (i.e. it doesn't have a `self` argument).

If you need to call one such trait methods then you will need to use a `match`, much like you're doing (*). This can be made more ergonomic through the use of crates like e.g. [`enum_dispatch`](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch).

If the methods you need to call are all object-safe, you can create a wrapper trait with a blanket implementation that only includes the object-safe methods:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait NotObjectSafe {
    fn generic_method<T: Debug> (&self, val: &T);
    fn static_method();
    fn object_safe_method (&self);
}

impl NotObjectSafe for i32 {
    fn generic_method<T: Debug> (&self, val: &T) {
        println!("Generic method for {self}: {val:?}");
    }
    
    fn static_method() {
        println!("Static method for i32");
    }
    
    fn object_safe_method (&self) {
        println!("Object safe method for {self}");
    }
}

trait ObjectSafeWrapper {
    fn object_safe_method (&self);
}

impl<T: NotObjectSafe> ObjectSafeWrapper for T {
    fn object_safe_method (&self) {
        NotObjectSafe::object_safe_method (self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let i = 42;
    let r: &dyn ObjectSafeWrapper = &i;
    r.object_safe_method();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e20210d6a56fea58034e51ca265280b)

---

(*) If you need access to a limited number of generic methods you can still make a wrapper trait, but you need to provide non-generic versions of the generic methods for the types you plan to use:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait NotObjectSafe {
    fn generic_method<T: Debug> (&self, val: &T);
}

impl NotObjectSafe for i32 {
    fn generic_method<T: Debug> (&self, val: &T) {
        println!("Generic method for {self}: {val:?}");
    }
}

trait ObjectSafeWrapper {
    fn generic_method_on_f32 (&self, val: &f32);
}

impl<T: NotObjectSafe> ObjectSafeWrapper for T {
    fn generic_method_on_f32 (&self, val: &f32) {
        NotObjectSafe::generic_method (self, val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let i = 42;
    let r: &dyn ObjectSafeWrapper = &i;
    r.generic_method_on_f32 (&3.14);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=06cbe7347a7d86cdff1f338a28e157ff)

Comment: I have to use static methods so `dyn` is not an option. Is there any way to generate a `match` for all the combinations using a macro or could you provide an example using `enum_dispatch`?